# MySQL/PHP puts an enter and whitespace after record echo

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo'<img src="'.$row['url'].'"/>';
  }
}
```

The following outputs the row URL with a whitespace and a linebreak after it.

```
src="upload/imgurl.JPG <-- (Here is a space and on the next line the ")
"
```

When I manually type in a URL manually it all works fine. Also the URLs in the database are without space, breakline, etc.

Why does PHP/MySQL put this break and space after my string? How could I solve it without hardcoding a trim or something like that?

Comment: You can use function trim() http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: "why does php/mysql put this break and space after my string" - php/mysql doesn't put anything. There must be a newline symbol in your database.

Comment: nope there is none. I noticed it was doing this on diffrent site before.. Anyway Ill just trim it

Comment: @Merijndk "nope there is none" - but where can it come from? You are printing the value taken from the database.

Comment: Yeah thats the thing im wondering and the reason I pref not to just trim it. Its all good in the db. then I print it out of the db and suddenly these spaces get added..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good to use `trim()` function before adding data in the db. Now you can also `trim()` the output-data. Its not a big deal at all

Answer (score 3):

Trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string. Here:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $trimmed = trim($row['url']);
      echo'<img src="'.$trimmed.'"/>';
  }
}
```